# How to disable all widgets on homescreen

Tags: widget, apk

Is it possible to deactivate the widgets on the homescreen? Maybe with a simple app or just by deleting the widget files on the device? I am using a MDM tool to configure the devices and we don't want to use a lockdown screen.

Can I create a shortcut on the homescreen for an app as well. (maybe writing an apk that sets an icon)